# Limit plot bank upto marker line

Tags: highcharts

I am looking to add plotbands/zones to my highchart. I am referring to dark yellow bands below the marker points.

[image]

I have seen a few examples of how to draw plotBands but none seem to give the option of limit the height of plotBand.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-addplotband/

```
 chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                from: 5.5,
                to: 7.5,
                color: '#FCFFC5',
                id: 'plot-band-1'
            });
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: No, `plotBands` can not be limited in this manner. There are various potential work arounds if you can be more specific - I am not clear what portion of your image is meant to represent a plot band.

Comment: I think that you can use zones in case of your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/jgyxcbxo/ It this is an answer on your question, I will post it as an answer

Comment: @jlbriggs i have updated the question

Comment: I am still not seeing any plot bands in your illustration. You say: "I am referring to dark yellow bands below the marker points." I do not see this in your image. Do you mean the area fill?? If that's the case, then you just need to use an `area` series type instead of a `line`.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński is there any way to add some kind of seperation between the zones (since all my zones are the same color)

Comment: You can use area series type and add break lines using renderer.path: http://jsfiddle.net/jgyxcbxo/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński if you can place your comment in an answer then I can mark it so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use area series type and add break lines in your load (and redraw) event callback function, using chart.renderer.path:

```
  var breakLines = function(chart) {
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
    $('.breakLines').remove();
    Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p) {
      chart.renderer.path([
        'M',
        xAxis.toPixels(p.x),
        yAxis.toPixels(0),
        'L',
        xAxis.toPixels(p.x),
        yAxis.toPixels(p.y)
      ]).attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: 'white',
        zIndex: 3
      }).addClass('breakLines').add()
    });
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/jgyxcbxo/1/